# Kernel Panic - Not Syncing : Fatal Exception in Interrupt

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, uefi, ralink

Right from the very beginning, I have a new UEFI pre-installed Windows 8 system on which I installed a dual boot 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. It was working fine except today when more than twice, my system crashed with a black screen showing the following message at the end:

> Kernel Panic - Not Syncing : Fatal exception in Interrupt

I googled this and got to no particular solution. After two such crashes, I copied the log file in dmesg.0 into these two paste URLs:

1. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5855604/
2. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5855647/

These two have separate log files of separate crashed sessions. Also, if its relevant here, I have a RaLink wireless adapter for which I had to manually install its driver. RaLink 3290.

It might be a problem with the wireless driver because it shows up only when switching on the wireless. Please help.

Comment: Also, there is this bug report from which I couldnt make out anything except that it is for BroadCom and I have RaLink.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...x/+bug/1181392

Comment: did you find solution for this??

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the drivers, please report at Launchpad.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).